# AzureDevOps Tree-query with 3 filtered levels

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-boards

I need a tree query to display stuctured view of my backlog. I need to see epics, features und product backlog items in a hierarchical order. I found out how to filter elements of the 1st level (epics) an how to filter elements of the last level (pbi). But what i need is to filter elements of  the second level. Is there any way to get it to work?

best
martin

i tried different combinations of filters

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but there is a trick:

```
Parent
(
   Work item type: Epic
   and ...
   and ...
)


Child
(
    work item type: feature
    and ...
    and ...
)
or 
(
    work item type: PBI
    and ...
    and ...
)
```

Tree based Query, Following Parent/Child.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent
(
   Work item type: Epic
   and tags contains 'epic-filter'
   and ...
)


Child
(
    work item type: feature
    and tags contains 'feature-filter'
    and ...
)
or 
(
    work item type: PBI
    and tags contains 'PBI-filter'
    and ...
)
```

The query would find all ...

1. features filtered by feature-filter underneath the filtered epics
   AND
2. PBIs filtered by PBI-filter underneath the filtered epics

... but unfortunately also their direct parent. That means that the query would only find filtered PBIs filtered by the PBI-filter, but also its  parent-features outside the feature-filter ;(